# Could not be processed by Zeroturnaround JRebel

Tags: spring, eclipse, jrebel

Env:

1. JRebel for Eclipse 7.0.11
2. Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers. Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2) Build id: 20160218-0600
3. Spring 4.2.7.RELEASE

If I used the JRebel, I got this error:

```
    2017-07-11 01:07:30 JRebel: ERROR Class 'org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet' could not be processed by org.zeroturnaround.javarebel.integration.spring.cbp.DispatcherServletCBP@org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader@6524bbeb: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.NotFoundException: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.CtClassType.getClassFile3(SourceFile:213)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.CtClassType.makeFieldCache(SourceFile:900)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.CtClassType.getMembers(SourceFile:891)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.CtClassType.getDeclaredField2(SourceFile:1025)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.CtClassType.getField2(SourceFile:979)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.CtClassType.getField2(SourceFile:987)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.CtClassType.getField2(SourceFile:994)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.CtClassType.getField(SourceFile:960)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.CtClass.getField(SourceFile:835)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.fieldAccess(SourceFile:837)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atFieldRead(SourceFile:803)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atMember(SourceFile:988)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.compiler.JvstTypeChecker.atMember(SourceFile:66)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.compiler.ast.Member.accept(SourceFile:39)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atCallExpr(SourceFile:665)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.compiler.JvstTypeChecker.atCallExpr(SourceFile:157)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.compiler.ast.CallExpr.accept(SourceFile:46)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.compiler.CodeGen.doTypeCheck(SourceFile:242)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(SourceFile:330)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(SourceFile:50)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(SourceFile:351)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(SourceFile:50)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.compiler.Javac.compileStmnt(SourceFile:567)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.CtBehavior.insertAfterAdvice(SourceFile:892)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.CtBehavior.insertAfter(SourceFile:851)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.CtBehavior.insertAfter(SourceFile:792)
    at org.zeroturnaround.javarebel.integration.spring.cbp.DispatcherServletCBP.process(DispatcherServletCBP.java:44)
    at org.zeroturnaround.javarebel.integration.support.JavassistClassBytecodeProcessor.process(SourceFile:78)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.tt.a(SourceFile:376)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.tt.a(SourceFile:365)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.tt.a(SourceFile:322)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.SDKIntegrationImpl.runBytecodeProcessors(SourceFile:34)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.rh.transform(SourceFile:106)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2888)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1172)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1558)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:152)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5280)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.NotFoundException: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.CtClassType.getClassFile3(SourceFile:201)
    ... 51 more

2017-07-11 01:07:30 JRebel: ERROR Class 'ch.qos.logback.core.ContextBase' could not be processed by org.zeroturnaround.jrebel.integration.logback.cbp.ContextBaseCBP@org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader@6524bbeb: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.NotFoundException: ch.qos.logback.core.Context
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.CtClassType.getClassFile3(SourceFile:213)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.CtClassType.makeFieldCache(SourceFile:900)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.CtClassType.getMembers(SourceFile:891)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.CtClassType.getDeclaredField2(SourceFile:1025)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.CtClassType.getField2(SourceFile:979)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.CtClassType.getField2(SourceFile:987)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.CtClassType.getField(SourceFile:960)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.CtClass.getField(SourceFile:835)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.fieldAccess(SourceFile:837)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atFieldRead(SourceFile:803)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atMember(SourceFile:988)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.compiler.JvstTypeChecker.atMember(SourceFile:66)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.compiler.ast.Member.accept(SourceFile:39)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atCallExpr(SourceFile:665)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.compiler.JvstTypeChecker.atCallExpr(SourceFile:157)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.compiler.ast.CallExpr.accept(SourceFile:46)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.compiler.CodeGen.doTypeCheck(SourceFile:242)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(SourceFile:330)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(SourceFile:50)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.compiler.Javac.compileStmnt(SourceFile:567)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.CtBehavior.insertAfterAdvice(SourceFile:892)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.CtBehavior.insertAfter(SourceFile:851)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.CtBehavior.insertAfter(SourceFile:792)
    at org.zeroturnaround.javarebel.integration.support.CBPs$DirectProcessorImpl.insertAfterLeafCtors(SourceFile:229)
    at org.zeroturnaround.jrebel.integration.logback.cbp.ContextBaseCBP.process(ContextBaseCBP.java:12)
    at org.zeroturnaround.javarebel.integration.support.JavassistClassBytecodeProcessor.process(SourceFile:78)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.tt.a(SourceFile:376)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.tt.a(SourceFile:365)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.tt.a(SourceFile:322)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.SDKIntegrationImpl.runBytecodeProcessors(SourceFile:34)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.rh.transform(SourceFile:106)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2888)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1172)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1558)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.rp.a(SourceFile:118)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.rp.a(SourceFile:299)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.rh.transform(SourceFile:122)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2888)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1172)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1558)
    at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<init>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:59)
    at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:50)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:150)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:124)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:412)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:357)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:155)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:132)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:351)
    at org.springframework.web.context.AbstractContextLoaderInitializer.<init>(AbstractContextLoaderInitializer.java:44)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer.<init>(AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer.java:60)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer.<init>(AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer.java:39)
    at id.co.bippo.springapp.BippoWebAppInitializer.<init>(BippoWebAppInitializer.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.__newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:152)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5280)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.NotFoundException: ch.qos.logback.core.Context
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.CtClassType.getClassFile3(SourceFile:201)
    ... 76 more
```

and

```
2017-07-11 01:07:34 JRebel: ERROR Class 'org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory' could not be processed by org.zeroturnaround.javarebel.integration.spring.core.cbp.CachingMetadataReaderFactoryCBP@org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader@6524bbeb: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.NotFoundException: org.springframework.core.type.classreading.MetadataReaderFactory
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.CtClassType.getClassFile3(SourceFile:213)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.CtClassType.makeFieldCache(SourceFile:900)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.CtClassType.getMembers(SourceFile:891)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.CtClassType.getDeclaredField2(SourceFile:1025)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.CtClassType.getField2(SourceFile:979)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.CtClassType.getField2(SourceFile:987)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.CtClassType.getField2(SourceFile:994)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.CtClassType.getField(SourceFile:960)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.CtClass.getField(SourceFile:835)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.fieldAccess(SourceFile:837)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atFieldRead(SourceFile:803)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atMember(SourceFile:988)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.compiler.JvstTypeChecker.atMember(SourceFile:66)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.compiler.ast.Member.accept(SourceFile:39)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atCallExpr(SourceFile:665)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.compiler.JvstTypeChecker.atCallExpr(SourceFile:157)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.compiler.ast.CallExpr.accept(SourceFile:46)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atCallExpr(SourceFile:665)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.compiler.JvstTypeChecker.atCallExpr(SourceFile:157)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.compiler.ast.CallExpr.accept(SourceFile:46)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.compiler.CodeGen.doTypeCheck(SourceFile:242)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(SourceFile:330)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(SourceFile:50)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.compiler.Javac.compileStmnt(SourceFile:567)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.CtBehavior.insertAfterAdvice(SourceFile:892)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.CtBehavior.insertAfter(SourceFile:851)
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.CtBehavior.insertAfter(SourceFile:792)
    at org.zeroturnaround.javarebel.integration.spring.core.cbp.CachingMetadataReaderFactoryCBP.process(CachingMetadataReaderFactoryCBP.java:26)
    at org.zeroturnaround.javarebel.integration.support.JavassistClassBytecodeProcessor.process(SourceFile:78)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.tt.a(SourceFile:376)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.tt.a(SourceFile:365)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.tt.a(SourceFile:322)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.SDKIntegrationImpl.runBytecodeProcessors(SourceFile:34)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.rh.transform(SourceFile:106)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2888)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1172)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1558)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.<init>(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:81)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.<init>(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.getClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner(AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.java:276)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.java:190)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.__refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:609)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.__refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:510)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4797)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5291)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.NotFoundException: org.springframework.core.type.classreading.MetadataReaderFactory
    at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.CtClassType.getClassFile3(SourceFile:201)
    ... 60 more
```

If I unused the JRebel, the error is gone...

Answer (score 2):

Using Tomcat older than 7.0.70? Version 7.0.12 of JRebel was released that should fix these errors, so try updating your JRebel for Eclipse plugin.